# Having issue identify a number pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am new to RegEx and I am having some difficult time when trying to detect a pattern.

I want to identify a number that is between 4000-4999 but at the same time must NOT be preceded or followed by another number with an optional character of either space or hyphen "-".

For example:
4567  (match)

I have 4999 roses (match)

1234567 days are gone  (no match)

My water supply account is 123 4567 89 (no match)

Howdy, my cell number is 123-4567-89 (no match)

I tried below pattern

```
(?<!(\d))\b4\d{3}\b(?!(\d))
```

but it still gives me a match for 123 4567 - I guess there is something special about \b?

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: `with consideration of space or hyphen "-".` What exactly do you mean by "with consideration of"?

Comment: Hi CertainPerformance, I mean space or hyphen may or may not be present, I should probably rephrase it to "optional"

Comment: Thanks. Does the whole pattern need to match the 4 digits, or could a subgroup match work? (reason I'm asking is that the optional space or hyphen makes a lookbehind non-fixed width)

Comment: `\b` is `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`. For "123 4567", `\b` matches the "vertical boundary" between the space and 4 (and also that between 3 and the space). Hence `(?<!\d)\b4\d{3}\b(?!\d)` will indeed get a match because what is in front of `\b4` is a space, not a numeric digit.

Comment: BTW it may be better if you can tag the programming language you're using in the question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I need to match the 4 digits. In fact, the explanation from ytu gave me some idea - I added a \s into my look ahead/behind which appears to solve the scenario for "space" (?<!(\d\s))\b4\d{3}\b(?!(\s\d)). I can create a similar equation for hyphen separately.

Comment: Thanks @ytu - I learned something new from you!!!

Comment: correction: (?<!(\d[\s-]))\b4\d{3}\b(?!([\s-]\d)) shall satisfy all my requirement :) Thanks guys.

Comment: @EricSun I posted a [better solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300060/3832970) as it does not rely on word boundaries and may even match in between underscores and when glued to words. If you really want to avoid that, then you need to use word boundaries by all means.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?<!\d[\s-]|\d)4\d{3}(?![\s-]?\d)
```

In .NET, JavaScript ECMAScript 2018 compliant environments, or PyPi regex, where lookbehinds patterns can contain `?`, `*`, `+` and `{min,}` quantifiers, you may shorten it to

```
(?<!\d[\s-]?)4\d{3}(?![\s-]?\d)
```

Or, in case alternation with different length is not supported (as in Boost or Python), use

```
(?<!\d[\s-])(?<!\d)4\d{3}(?![\s-]?\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pd6l9q/1) and [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Pd6l9q/2) (and a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%5B%5Cs-%5D%3F%294%5Cd%7B3%7D%28%3F!%5B%5Cs-%5D%3F%5Cd%29&i=For%20example%3A%204567%20%28match%29%0D%0AI%20have%204999%20roses%20%28match%29%0D%0A1234567%20days%20are%20gone%20%28no%20match%29%0D%0AMy%20water%20supply%20account%20is%20123%204567%2089%20%28no%20match%29%0D%0AHowdy%2C%20my%20cell%20number%20is%20123-4567-89%20%28no%20match%29%0D%0Ano%20match%20for%20123%204567)).

**Details**

- `(?<!\d[\s-]|\d)` / `(?<!\d[\s-]?)` / `(?<!\d[\s-])(?<!\d)` - no digit and a whitespace/`-` *and* no digit immediately to the left of the current position is allowed
- `4\d{3}` - `4` and any 3 digits
- `(?![\s-]?\d)` - immediately to the right, no 1 or 0 occurrences of a whitespace/`-` followed with a digit is allowed.

**NOTE** The solutions above do not rely on word boundaries and may even match in between underscores and when glued to words. If you really want to avoid that, then you need to use word boundaries by all means, e.g. `(?<!\d[\s-]|\d)\b4\d{3}\b(?![\s-]?\d)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Positive Lookahead` and `Positive Lookbehind` along with `[^ ]`? I think it can get you the desired results.

Pattern:

```
(?<=^|[^\d]{2})4[0-9]{3}(?=$|[^\d]{2})
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/PYPeCk/2/

Comment: Lookbehind problems: if the 4 digits are at the beginning of a line, this won't work. (eg `1234 days are gone`) Also, if the two characters before the 4 digits are a digit followed by something other than a digit or a dash, it won't match, even though it should.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I edited the code to make it match the beginning of a line. Thanks for your note. As for the second point, it seems highly unlikely even though it is possible.